# How do change the path of an application that launches from the launcher?

Tags: launcher, sublime-text

I'm using Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm in Unity. I recently installed package control for sublime text and this annoying error message about the LANG variable not being set keeps popping up. This is not true as `printenv` shows that it's set correctly. When I launch sublime via the termial using `subl` the error message doesn't appear. How do I make the launcher launch sublime in this fashion?